# Set visible to true in repeater using inline code

Tags: asp.net, random

I need to randomly set visible of row(index between 2 to 7) in a repeater to true.

I tried to declare a random number, when item index is equal to the random number, then set it to true

```
<div id="divSomething" runat="server" class="pull-center" visible=<%# (int r = new Random().Next(2, 7)) == Container.ItemIndex + 1) ? true : false %>>
```

But doesn't work. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: use javascript for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put the visible attribute in single quote also creating a variable inline like that is really unusual and you don't need an inline evaluation. I would create a public member variable in the code behind class;

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int r 
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(new Random().Next(2, 7));
        }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

then in the repeater:

```
<div id="divSomething" runat="server" class="pull-center" visible='<%# r ==(Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' >
```

Comment: Tried above code and it generate error "The name 'r' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but try to add some quotes to the visible property:

```
<... Visible='server code here' ...>
```